# Setting a variable as any decimal number

Tags: if-statement, integer

I want to create a program to tell if a year is a leap or not

I have:

year = int(input("What year?: ")

year_div_4 = year / 4
Now the first step is:

if year_div_4 = float then the year is a leap... then year/100 and year/400 and so

But if i want to use the if statement:

if year_div_4 == ______:

What should I put in the blank space, because if the answer is a float then it is a leap, but if i put float in there then I get a float = 'undefined error'

Because python thinks i want to set year_div_4 equal to a variable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Better use the %-operator (modulo) e.g.:

```
if (year % 4 == 0):
    print(f"{year} is divisible by 4")
```

Here is a complete example for leap year:

```
year = int(input("What year?: "))

if ((year % 400 == 0) or ((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 > 0))):
    print(f"{year} is leap year")
else:
    print(f"{year} is not leap year")
```

If you really want to check if a variable is of type `float` try this with different values for `year`:

```
year_div_4 = year / 4

if (isinstance(year_div_4, float)):
    print(f"{year_div_4} is of type float")

print(f"type is {type(year_div_4)}")
```

You will see that the `type` doesn't help you for a divisibility check, because in python the result of `year / 4` will always be of type `float` even if `year` is divisible by 4.